# How to create a Publish / Subscribe architecture using the CZMQ-4.0.2 new zsock API?

Tags: c++, c, zeromq

I want to create a Publish / Subscribe architecture, using CZMQ-4.0.2, but I am not able to understand how to use the new **`zsock`** APIs.

Can anyone point me to some examples using the new APIs?

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel : Hi, After some trial and error, I am able to write some working code now. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you post an answer describing what you did, you can accept it, and it might even help someone else.

Comment: I'd like to see that too, I really need an answer to this question ^^

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### tldr;

[Examples are on the bottom of the site](http://czmq.zeromq.org/czmq4-0:zsock)

#### Little explanation

I'm assuming that you're asking for CZMQ specific usage, not how to use ZeroMQ sockets, and what are the quirks of PUB/SUB pattern.

When using CZMQ you don't need to worry about context, it is done internally. `zsock_new` functions family returns pointer to `zsock_t`, an opaque identifier for socket. You need to remember to call `zsock_destroy(&socket)` when you're done with it, to avoid memory leaks.

In most common usage you don't need to worry about connecting and binding because `zsock_new_XXX` takes care of that. To know what action was taken you can look to [manual](http://czmq.zeromq.org/czmq4-0:zsock).

> ```
> //  Create a PUB socket. Default action is bind.
> CZMQ_EXPORT zsock_t *
>     zsock_new_pub (const char *endpoint);
> //  Create a SUB socket, and optionally subscribe to some prefix string. Default
> //  action is connect.
> CZMQ_EXPORT zsock_t *
>     zsock_new_sub (const char *endpoint, const char *subscribe);
> ```

If you're planning to do some unusual binding/connecting, you can add a prefix to `endpoint`. `@` indicates bind, `>` connect.

```
zsock_t *sock = zsock_new_push("@ipc://test");
```

Now, to send message you can use plenty of methods (`zsock_send`, `zmsg_send`, `zstr_send`, `zstr_sendx`, `zstr_sendf`, `zframe_send`), most generic is `zsock_send`. It has printf like prototype, where you need to pass a *picture* of a message. Each char in this string represents single frame in message (or more frames because you can also pass another message). It is described  in [here](http://czmq.zeromq.org/czmq4-0:zsock):

> ```
> //  Send a 'picture' message to the socket (or actor). The picture is a
> //  string that defines the type of each frame. This makes it easy to send
> //  a complex multiframe message in one call. The picture can contain any
> //  of these characters, each corresponding to one or two arguments:
> //
> //      i = int (signed)
> //      1 = uint8_t
> //      2 = uint16_t
> //      4 = uint32_t
> //      8 = uint64_t
> //      s = char *
> //      b = byte *, size_t (2 arguments)
> //      c = zchunk_t *
> //      f = zframe_t *
> //      h = zhashx_t *
> //      U = zuuid_t *
> //      p = void * (sends the pointer value, only meaningful over inproc)
> //      m = zmsg_t * (sends all frames in the zmsg)
> //      z = sends zero-sized frame (0 arguments)
> //      u = uint (deprecated)
> //
> //  Note that s, b, c, and f are encoded the same way and the choice is
> //  offered as a convenience to the sender, which may or may not already
> //  have data in a zchunk or zframe. Does not change or take ownership of
> //  any arguments. Returns 0 if successful, -1 if sending failed for any
> //  reason.
> CZMQ_EXPORT int
> zsock_send (void *self, const char *picture, ...);
> ```

One what may be unclear is this `void *self`, it is actually our `zsock_t *` returned from zsock_new. In prototype, it is declared as `void *` because this function also accepts `zactor_t *`.

Important: `Does not change or take ownership of any arguments.`. You need to free/destroy data after sending.

Receiving looks very similar. It is like sscanf, and `zsock_recv` creates objects, so again, you need to take care of memory.

Big difference in behavior between ZeroMQ and CZMQ is LINGER socket option. For ZeroMQ it was infinite (-1), where CZMQ has a default value of 0 (no blocking). So anytime when you'll have `zsock_send` followed by `zsock_destroy`, your message may not be delivered. Linger value can be set individually for the socket by using `zsock_set_linger`, or globally `zsys_set_linger`.

Example of Publisher

```
#include <czmq.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  zsock_t *socket = zsock_new_pub("ipc://example.sock");
  assert(socket);

  while(!zsys_interrupted) {
    zsys_info("Publishing");
    zsock_send(socket, "sss", "TOPIC", "MESSAGE PART", "ANOTHER");
    zclock_sleep(1000);
  }

  zsock_destroy(&socket);
  return 0;
}
```

Example of Subscriber

```
#include <czmq.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  zsock_t *socket = zsock_new_sub("ipc://example.sock", "TOPIC");
  assert(socket);

  char *topic;
  char *frame;
  zmsg_t *msg;
  int rc = zsock_recv(socket, "sm", &topic, &msg);
  assert(rc == 0);

  zsys_info("Recv on %s", topic);
  while(frame = zmsg_popstr(msg)) {
    zsys_info("> %s", frame);
    free(frame);
  }
  free(topic);
  zmsg_destroy(&msg);

  zsock_destroy(&socket);
  return 0;
}
```